# MySql innoDB auto increment lock workaround

Tags: mysql, multithreading, innodb

I have a project in which I insert a lot if info to a table with an auto increment primary key per second and do that with multi-threading which means that there are many threads that tries to insert a new row to that table. Because there is a lock on the table for insert queries, I cant perform inserts concurrently and therefore I cant get maximum performance from the threads...

Is there a way to overcome this lock?

Comment: How many inserts/second on average?  Maximum?  How often do you get a locking problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the **innodb_autoinc_lock_mode** to 1 in the my.cnf. Then there is no LOCK for Auto_increment. Then it is possible that you have holes in the Values if one Thead rollback an see sample

```
MariaDB [test]> show variables like 'innodb_autoinc_lock_mode';
+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| innodb_autoinc_lock_mode | 1     |
+--------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**sample 1**

```
MariaDB [test]> start transaction;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> insert into autoinc VALUES(NULL,'hello');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)



thread 2 ------------------>    MariaDB [test]> start transaction;
thread 2 ------------------>    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

thread 2 ------------------>    MariaDB [test]> insert into autoinc VALUES(NULL,'world');
thread 2 ------------------>    Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

thread 2 ------------------>    MariaDB [test]> commit;
thread 2 ------------------>    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

thread 2 ------------------>    MariaDB [test]>


MariaDB [test]> commit;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select * from autoinc;
+----+-------+
| id | d     |
+----+-------+
|  1 | hello |
|  2 | world |
+----+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]>
```

**sample 2 with rollback**

```
MariaDB [test]> start transaction;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> insert into autoinc VALUES(NULL,'Guten');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

thread 2 ------------------>    MariaDB [test]> start transaction;
thread 2 ------------------>    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

thread 2 ------------------>    MariaDB [test]> insert into autoinc VALUES(NULL,'Tag');
thread 2 ------------------>    Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

thread 2 ------------------>    MariaDB [test]> commit;
thread 2 ------------------>    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [test]> rollback;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select * from autoinc;
+----+-------+
| id | d     |
+----+-------+
|  1 | hello |
|  2 | world |
|  4 | Tag   |
+----+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]>
```

Comment: But if I know for sure that once I insert a row I don't want to rollback except in case of db failure which I assume does not suppose to happen very often,  then it is not very bad practice to set the lock to 1 and I can assume that the amount of holes will be very low,  can I?

Comment: correct, but see first what **show variables like 'innodb_autoinc_lock_mode';** says. the default Value is 1. see : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/xtradbinnodb-server-system-variables/#innodb_autoinc_lock_mode

Comment: I will but I know there is a lock because when I try to insert cunncorently I get an Sql exception that says cannot acquire lock...

Comment: which DB Version you are using and can you give me a error number ?

Comment: Im using mysql 5.7 and the error is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction.

Comment: The error doesn't show up when I'm using synchronized around the insert query execution (the code is in java)

Comment: "Cannot acquire lock" means that _something else is wrong_.  Please provide more info, including discusion of autocommit and BEGIN...COMMIT usage.

Answer (score 0):

**My case.**

```
vi /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

# innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 0

systemctl restart mysql
```